# Build and bind JSON collection to controller action's parameters using AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

There are a lot of question like this, but I cannot find what I'm doing wrong in my specific case. I am trying to build a JSON collection of objects and bind it to my controller action's parameter.

At the moment, I am only trying to bind Name property to the list. The only issue I can think of might be my JSON collection structure.

AJAX:

```
function GetFilteredDatatablesValues() {
    var data = {
        Columns: []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var column = {
            Name: "name" + i
        };
        data.Columns.push(column);
    }

    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Client/DatatablesSearchTest',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        error: function (response) {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```

Controller action:

```
public JsonResult DatatablesSearchTest(List<DataTableColumn> Columns) //Columns contains 0 items
{
    List<DataTableColumn> test = Columns;

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Model:

```
public class DataTableColumn
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Orderable { get; set; }
    public bool Searchable { get; set; }
    public Search Search { get; set; }
    public DataTableColumn()
    {
        Search = new Search();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm your code work well for `.Net Framework`, but not in `.netcore`:

The simple solution to fix the issue :

1 : Put the property`List<DataTableColumn> Columns` into `RootModel`:

```
public class RootModel
{
    public List<DataTableColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

2 : Change the signature of the action, by adding `[FromBody]RootModel rootModel` like a parameter:

```
public JsonResult DatatablesSearchTest([FromBody]RootModel rootModel) //Columns contains 0 items
{
    //List<DataTableColumn> test = Columns;

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

> Note that, without `[FromBody]` will gives you null object.

I hope this help you fix the issue.

Comment: Yes I have and thank you for the answer. But I just cannot get this to work.

Comment: @Lukas your project is .NetCore or .NetFramework? this solution work just fine for .netcore application.

Comment: It is a .NetCore project. I will continue to figure it out.

Comment: Sajid, this worked. Out of habit, I had put a constructor in the `RootModel` that initialized a `Columns = new List<DatatableColumn>()`. I removed it and it worked. Thank you Sajid!

Answer (score 1):

The data you send looks like this:

```
{
    Columns: [
        { column 1 },
        { column 2 }
    ]
}
```

But the data the controller expects looks like this:

```
[
    { column 1 },
    { column 2 }
]
```

I would recommend you to always create a single model that reflects exactly what you want to send to the server. So your controller action would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DatatablesSearchTest(SearchModel model)
{
    List<DataTableColumn> test = model.Columns;
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

```
public class SearchModel
{
    List<DataTableColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, poke. I'm still having trouble with this. Columns remains of count 0. Would you mind providing more information, maybe how the object structure for JSON should be generated?

Comment: A count of 0? So no `null` but there is an actual list and that list just has no items? Then you must be doing something else, or sending an empty array to begin with.

Comment: Poke, you are right. I was initializing `Columns = new List<DatatableColumn>()` in the constructor. While I have things set up a bit differently now, your explanation helped me understand what was going on and I got it working. Thank you! And thank you again for the answers you provided in my past questions.